# When try to fetch data from db using fetch all it fetch decimal value in the format Decimal('1341223.000') when it returns to json file it hit error

Tags: python

`cursor.fetchall`
from below code  it takes data in decimal type as decimal('685.000') so i need to solve this problem other data is fetched properly without attaching format to it but for decimal it retrieves `decimal('6734.000')` like this any one pls help!

```
result=cursor.fetchall()
columns=[item[0] for item in cursor.description]       
final_data=[(dict(zip(columns,rv))) for rv in result]
```

I need to solve this problem, does any one know any solution?

Comment: You can change your query so it casts the `DECIMAL` column to `FLOAT`. Or you can call `float()` in Python to convert the `Decimal` value to `float`.

Comment: Why is this a problem? That's just how it's printed. If you use it in calculations it will do the right thing.

Comment: @Barmar while printing datas that are fetched other data are printed correctly only data with datatype decimal is printing like that i want the data not wraped with data type its only issue

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Convert `Decimal` instances in `rv` to `float`.

```
from decimal import *

rv = [[float(x) if isinstance(x, Decimal) else x for x in row] for row in rv]
```

Comment: While trying showing error "Decimal" is not defined

Comment: You need to import it from the `decimal` module.

Comment: $(document).on('click', '#btngeneratecolumns', function () {
 validation();
 if (validstatus == true) {
  let objectname = $('#object-name option:selected').text();
  let objectname2 = $('#object-name2 option:selected').text();
  $.ajax({
   type: 'GET',
   url: `/views/generatecolumns/${objectname}`,
   dataType: 'json',
   success: function (response) {
    if (response.message == 'success') {
     values = response.columns
     populatemodal(response); i want to know how i can retrive the data from objectname2 how i can pass this  to url

Comment: ```url:`/views/generatecolumns/${objectname}/${objectname2}` ```

Comment: @app.route('/views/generatecolumns/<objname>',methods=['GET'])
def get_obj_details(objname):
    data=bo.getobjdata(objname)
    print(data)
    return data WHEN I TRY TO CHANGE IT IN ROUTE HERE BUT CANAT FIND ERROR

Comment: Of course you need a different route when there are two parameters.

Comment: Why are we having this conversation in the comments about a totally unrelated question? If you have a new problem, post it as a question.

Comment: is it possible to read it from api and store it in a json instead of reading it by url

Comment: Please post a new question, I'm ignoring any comments you post here.